# Como faço para o Django "enxergar" o CSS?

Tags: html5, python, css3, django

Estou escrevendo uma aplicação Django e Python, e estou com um problema 
    na parte de templates, executando localmente o Django achou a template e 
    eu consegui visualisar ela através do `localhost:8080/home`, acontece que a 
    folha de estilo (CSS) não esta sendo baixada (localizada) pelo Django, 
    ele está exibindo a template em HTML apenas.

A árvore do projeto se encontra da seguinte maneira:

```
Library
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ admin.py
  |_ models.py
  |_ tests.py
  |_ views.py
  |_ urls.py
  |_ templates
      |_ templates
          |_ index.html
          |_ base.html
          |_ css
          |_ js
          |_ fonts
```

Meu settings.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Django settings for Chameleon project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

#PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'gb)bi45$q*#()1gbf_1td3x7+7#%3zk4%&)$^f6@8bpndb$a12'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin', #Sistema de administracao Backend
    'django.contrib.auth', #Sistema de autenticao
    'django.contrib.contenttypes', #Tipos de conteudo 
    'django.contrib.sessions', #Trata as sessoes
    'django.contrib.messages', #Gerencia mensagens de erro sucesso etc
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', #Gerencia arquivos estaticos (html, CSS, JavaScript)
    'Library', #Adicionando nome do projeto para criação das tabelas no DB
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Chameleon.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Chameleon.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'USER': '', 
        'PASSWORD':'',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join
```

Minha views.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
#from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

# Create your views here.   
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('templates/index.html')
```

Meu HTML index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Bootstrap Icone da pagina -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

    <title>Chameleon</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin" role="form">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" required>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Lembre-me
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Visualizei pelo modo desenvolvedor do navegador que os 3 arquivos CSS 
    não estão sendo encontrados, esta retornando 404 not found.

Meu python é o Python27 o Django é o 1.6.2

Comment: "Visualizei pelo modo desenvolvedor do navegador que os 3 arquivos CSS não estão sendo encontrados, esta retornando 404 not found." Consegues ver o caminho do CSS ai? Se sim verifica se está no sitio certo.

Comment: O caminho CSS esta correto!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Entendo que estejam faltando três coisas para resolver o seu problema:

### 1) Definir o caminho para os recursos estáticos

Existe uma variável que você adiciona no `settings.py`, chamada `STATICFILES_DIRS`, onde você pode adicionar os caminhos para os seus recursos estáticos (arquivos css, js, imagens, etc). Por exemplo:

```
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   '/caminho/para/recursos/estaticos/aqui',
)
```

No servidor de testes isso é o suficiente, mas em produção também é necessário rodar o `python manage.py collecstatic` para copiar os arquivos para a pasta certa.

### 2) Definir o URL dos recursos estáticos

No arquivo `urls.py`, é necessário fazer uma modificação para que os URLs sejam reconhecidos. Assim:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... seus URLs aqui
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

### 3) Adicionar prefixo para arquivos estáticos no template

Também está faltando o prefixo para arquivos estáticos no URL dos CSS.

Você pode resolver assim:

Antes:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Depois:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap-responsive.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Ou usar o método mais antigo:

```
<link href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[Nesta página da documentação do Django (em inglês)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/), estão maiores detalhes a respeito da configuração dos arquivos estáticos.

Answer (score 6):

Visto que o seu projeto esteja estruturado assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em resumo, como deve ficar configurado para carregar o seu `CSS`:

**settings.py**

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "projeto/static"),
    # '/var/www/static/',
)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #suas urls
)    
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**Template**

Sempre adicione no inicio do seu HTML o `{% load staticfiles %}`

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap-responsive.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```